# Batch Fuzzifying with ModelBuilder

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I am trying to run the Fuzzy Membership on simultaneous rasters in ModelBuilder and I am running into the problem (or bug) where it allows me to change the "Membership Type" but ends up defaulting to "MSSmall" irrespective of whether I change it in the batch table.
To put this in perspective, the "Remap" tool can be used to batch reclassify rasters, but the Fuzzy Membership tool defaults back to MSSmall even though it deceptively shows it processing with the chosen membership type.

Attached are two pics showing the ModelBuilder diagram I built and the resulting interface whence double-clicked in ArcCatalog.

[image: Diagram of Fuzzifying Multiple Rasters]
[image: Table that allows me to change Membership Type but ends up using "MSSmall" no matter what is set.]

Comment: Have you tried exporting the model to a script and analyzing the code behind it? Also, what version of ArcMap are you using?

Comment: Or changing the model properties to iterate a variable number of times depending upon the number of inputs.  Using ArcGis Desktop 10.1
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
# Script arguments
Raster_Dataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Fuzzy_function = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if Fuzzy_function == '#' or not Fuzzy_function:
    Fuzzy_function = "MSSMALL 1 1" # provide a default value if unspecified
# Local variables:
Output_raster = Raster_Dataset
# Process: Fuzzy Membership
arcpy.gp.FuzzyMembership_sa(Raster_Dataset, Output_raster, Fuzzy_function, "NONE")

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, your output script only has 2 parameters, when in reality it should have 3. I tried to recreate your script on my own and I was able to get it to work on 4 images with 4 different Fuzzy Functions. When I exported it to a script, there were 3 parameters. I don't see why your Hedge parameter is being hardcoded..

Do you have Service Pack 1 installed? My guess is no, because I do have it installed and there are more comments and a header outputted when I export to script.

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# fuzzify.py
# Created on: 2013-07-16 00:08:43.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Usage: fuzzify <Raster_Dataset> <Fuzzy_Function> <Hedge> 
# Description: 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

# Script arguments
Raster_Dataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

Fuzzy_Function = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if Fuzzy_Function == '#' or not Fuzzy_Function:
    Fuzzy_Function = "MSSMALL 1 1" # provide a default value if unspecified

Hedge = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
if Hedge == '#' or not Hedge:
    Hedge = "NONE" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
Output_raster = Raster_Dataset

# Process: Fuzzy Membership
arcpy.gp.FuzzyMembership_sa(Raster_Dataset, Output_raster, Fuzzy_Function, Hedge)
```

Comment: Yes, ArcGis 10.1 (isn't SP1 default)?
import arcpy

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

# Script arguments
Raster_Dataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

Fuzzy_function = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if Fuzzy_function == '#' or not Fuzzy_function:
    Fuzzy_function = "MSSMALL 1 1" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
Output_raster = Raster_Dataset

# Process: Fuzzy Membership
arcpy.gp.FuzzyMembership_sa(Raster_Dataset, Output_raster, Fuzzy_function, "NONE")

Comment: For some reason, I'm unable to get the formatting to display properly when I post the code.  In short, I removed the Hedge since it's unimportant to me.  That's why my script doesn't show that.  However, my script runs but the rub is that if you change the membership type to "MSLarge", and you examine the actual output, you'll notice that the fuzzification actually uses the "MSSmall" type.  So it's deceptive and i'd be curious if you looked at what the output fuzzified raster is compared with the input raster. do you see that even though you change the type to "MSLarge" it still uses MSSmall?

Comment: Correction... I don't have Service Pack 1 yet so perhaps I'll install and check my outcome again.

Comment: Besides looking visually different, I took a look at the output messages and it reported that MSLarge (and the others) were indeed being used. Also, if you want the code format in a comment (or post) use the backtick character ` around the code, which is the tilde key on a standard QWERTY keyboard, `like so`.

Comment: Right, but not only do they need to look visually different, they need to correspond to the membership type selected.  So if you need MSSmall and choose MSSmall as the membership type, you'll notice the colors get flip-flopped.  However, if you select MSLarge (and I know the output messages say they're using MSLarge) you should see the color patter is identical (ie. not flip-flopped).  Just run with a single continous raster and you should notice (like I have even after installing SP1), that selecting MSLarge produces the same results as selecting MSSmall (at least in the ModelBuilder)...

Comment: BTW - thx for the comment about the backtick character.  That will come in `handy`

Comment: Also, I'm going to try recreating the ModelBuilder from scratch under a different toolbox, since I recently updated to SP1 and the 64-bit geoprocessing patch for SP1 also.  I'll post my findings shortly.  If this continues to fail, I might look at ditching the "Fuzzy Membership" tool and have to write my own routine to classify the membership.

Comment: The issue remains and appears to have been around for awhile as depicted in this post on esri's forum [link]http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/41614-fuzzy-membership-in-modelbuilder-not-allowing-modification?highlight=fuzzy

Comment: Hmm well it would appear to be a bug, as I get the same results in a model as well as batching. I get different results when running the tool separately though...

Answer (score 1):

Issue has existed and was previously posted on ESRI's forum in 2011 [link]http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/41614-fuzzy-membership-in-modelbuilder-not-allowing-modification?highlight=fuzzy @Paul thanks for trying to look into this but it appears this bug/issue/defect with ArcGis 10.1 has never been resolved as it's easily reproducible.  You'll notice if you run the ModelBuilder twice, first using MSSmall, and then using MSLarge, the results are identical.  This is contrary to what the membership type classification is supposed to do.

Comment: File a bug report?